# Facing issues with Apache2 on Debain 10

Tags: configuration, debian, webserver, apache2, varnish

I tried to setup the Varnish on the Instance Debian 10 but then something goes wrong and I tried installing some apache2 modules like

> sudo a2enmod SSL
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy_http

But after enabling these modules when I restarted Apache2 I was unable to start the apache because there was something that was blocking port 443 and causing conflict with Apache2. When I removed the port Listen 443 from ports.conf file I was able to start the apache server but only on the 8080 port and on port 80 varnish is running but on the port 443, there is a service called httpd running which I am unable to find out from which config file it is configured.

The content of the ports.conf file is

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 8080

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Screenshot of the ports process running. I am unable to use port 443 and unable to stop that service httpd also. it is not linked with apache2 I tried stopping the apache but this service keeps on running.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### httpd

The `httpd` service usually refers to the Apache webserver. However, if you install Apache on Debian via `apt-get install apache2`, the actual service is called `apache2`. This is also reflected in your `netstat` output.

On Red Hat based system the service is called `httpd`. Is it possible that you compiled an Apache server from source on that same machine? Or did you accidentally install a package that is httpd-relate?

You can perform a `dpkg -l` to list the installed packages, maybe you'll find it there.

Anyway, please kill the `httpd` process and check if there's a systemd service that contains that service name. You can go into `/lib/systemd/system` and perform a `grep httpd *`.

### What about TLS in Varnish?

You shouldn't enable HTTPS on your system by using `mod_ssl`. You should install a TLS proxy that terminates the TLS session and then passes the plain HTTP connection to Varnish which in its turn will talk plain HTTP with Apache.

I advise you to use [Hitch](https://hitch-tls.org/), it's a TLS proxy that is developed by Varnish Software engineers. It's flexible, powerful and lightweight.

To install Hitch, you can find the official packages here: https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch.

Here's the documentation you might need: https://github.com/varnish/hitch/tree/master/docs

> A [Varnish Developer Portal](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers) tutorial about Hitch will be available some time next week.

Comment: I found a solution and tried the killall httpd which worked but there is still some issue with the SSL website not working

Comment: Submit the TLS/SSL problems in a separate question, and I'll be happy to assist.